# Different response between curl and openssl s_client

Tags: curl, openssl

I'm having a headache with some results.

Running the following command results in an HTTP 200 response:

```
$ curl -v -L www.example.com >/dev/null
```

while running this, and using the exact headers that `curl` uses results in an HTTP 403 response:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443
```

There is no problem with certificate, as `curl` and `openssl` verify it. I really can't think of anything to start digging this problem, so even just a wild guess is more than welcome!

The 403 response comes from Fortigaurd servers, reading "Web filter service error: all Fortiguard servers failed to respond".

I can provide more information, such as `curl` and `openssl` outputs, if needed.

Comment: Are you sure you got the line endings right? The HTTP specification requires a carriage return followed by a newline after each line. Just using a newline is not correct. I also noticed that you don't specify `-quiet` or `-ign_eof`. This means that `s_client` will parse your text for commands like `R` which might appear in your headers!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks, I didn't know about those parameters. Adding `-quiet` and also `-crlf` didn't help. Still getting 403.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm almost sure. I used emacs to change all endings to `crlf`, then copying that into my ssh session inside terminal. Unless copy/paste doesn't change line endings, all things should be fine.

Comment: (1) Copy/paste to a terminal very well _can_ change line endings; put your request in a file (and use `<file`) so you can edit exactly what you want. Be sure to include the empty line after the last header (that is a vital part of HTTP format). (2) The server (or its frontend) may want SNI, which `s_client` doesn't do by default; try adding `-servername $hostname`.

Comment: Your `curl` command is requesting on port 80 (HTTP), while your `openssl` command is requesting on port 443 (hopefully configured for HTTPS).  Check your server config.

Comment: @garethTheRed Yes you are correct. The server returns a redirect to `https` when using curl, which is handled by `-L` flag. Anyway, this does not change anything.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks! SNI was the problem. Adding mentioned flag solved issue. I will accept if you write your comment as an answer.

Comment: can you pls let me know how to add servername in this case, since different results are obtained when i run the HTTP request from command line and when i execute from py file :   " echo -en "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.wikipedia.org\r\n\r\n" | openssl s_client -connect wikipedia.org:443 -quiet " - gives HTTP request 200 OK . But when i run from python file - it gives INVALID request. From above post, i understand, servername is missing in my code as well so i have changed the cmd in py file to ""C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\openssl.exe s_client -connect wikipedia.org:443 -servername wikipedia -quiet"

Comment: in subsequent code : i m requesting for ""echo -en HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:www.wikipedia.org\r\n\r\n" - can anyone pls review and let me know , how can i get response as "OK" from py file

Comment: @danny `-servername wikipedia.org` is the correct one. You have to include full hostname, including subdomains (e.g. `www`). Also, it's better if you open a new question, since this question is not about python.

Comment: @vfsoraki - I have posted question in given link and awaiting for answer, you can have a look here with py script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756150/how-do-get-response-of-get-request-which-is-passed-using-popen-communicate/62784989?noredirect=1